# Install Victor Shoup's NTL library on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ntl

I am trying to install Victor Shoup's NTL package on a fully up-to-date Mac (latest OSX etc).

I downloaded the latest package (NTL 6.0.0) from http://www.shoup.net/ntl/download.html, unpacked it and ran the configure script

```
./configure PREFIX=$HOME/NTL NTL_GMP_LIP=on
```

to indicate that I want the package to be installed in a directory $HOME/NTL and that GMP is already installed in a standard place.

The compilation

```
make
```

appears to work fine.

However, when I do

```
make check
```

on the compiled code, then it starts the tests, does a few of them correctly, but then simply refuses to complete the test called ZZXFacTest.

According to the Activity Monitor, the test is just running, but it never seems to terminate.

On a recent Linux machine, the exact same process finishes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - the problem was to do with GMP.

When I turned off the "GMP is locally installed" flag, the checks worked, so I reinstalled the most recent version of GMP and it all worked...